# Is it possible to highlight an instance in geonode with spreadsheets?

Tags: geometry-nodes, spreadsheet

Currently learning geometry nodes by trying to create a rollercoaster. I am trying to get the value of rotation of an instance, but I need a specific one.

Is it possible to select it via Spreadsheet?

I would like to highlight the 11th instance, how do I do that?

[image]

Comment: AFAIK ...you can't. Maybe the viewer node is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Blender version you are using,you can add Row-Filters to the spreadsheet in its <kbd>N</kbd> panel, on the right.

At the moment the spreadsheet can only filter by values of rows in named columns, so you might have to create one of those, by storing an attribute as named. Here, the Index attribute is stored on instances as 'idx'.

[image]

Then you can set up one or more filters on the spreadsheet:

[image]

,, which you can activate or deactivate altogether, or independently.